# Trying to delete a file from directory

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo

I am trying to delete a file from a directory in an asp.net application, but I always get an exception that the file is being used by another process which is caused probably by the application itself.

this is the code

```
TableCell cell = (TableCell)PhotoGalleryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
    DirectoryInfo photoGalleryDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/GalleryImages/"));
    FileInfo[] imgFiles = photoGalleryDirectory.GetFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < imgFiles.Length; i++)
    {
        if (imgFiles[i].Name == cell.Text)
        {
            imgFiles[i].Delete();
        }
    }
```

how should i preform this action? 
thanks

I implemented this as a part of using the OnRowDeleting method from gridview so when i delete the photo from the database it will also delete the photo from the site's folder.

```
protected void PhotoGalleryGridView_OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    TableCell cell = (TableCell)PhotoGalleryGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
    DirectoryInfo photoGalleryDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/GalleryImages/"));
    FileInfo[] imgFiles = photoGalleryDirectory.GetFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < imgFiles.Length; i++)
    {
        if (imgFiles[i].Name == cell.Text)
        {
            imgFiles[i].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

I am more than willing to accept any other ideas for this action.

Comment: Before trying to resolve how to delete a locked file, I will try to know why and where the file has been locked!

Comment: OK, how call I tell what is locking the file?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using an object that encapsulates any resource, you have to make sure that when you are done with the object, the object's Dispose method is called.

This can be done more easily using the `using statement` in C#. The using statement simplifies the code that you have to write to create and then finally clean up the object. The using statement obtains the resource specified, executes the statements and finally calls the Dispose method of the object to clean up the object.......

Comment: which part of my code should I surround with the using statement?

Comment: You should have to check all connections related with that file.....If those connection are not disposed, they still create problem due to connection....So, I preferred to use using statement in those connection because it implments IDisposable interface......So, check out all connection related with that field....

Comment: good answer 1+ you should use using statment like so:
         FileInfo file;

        using( FileInfo[] imgFiles = photoGalleryDirectory.GetFiles   ())
     { 
      for (int i = 0; i < imgFiles.Length; i++) 
      { 
           if (imgFiles[i].Name == cell.Text) 
         { 
             file = imgFiles[i];
          } 
      }
}

file.Delete();

oh and you should mark the answer as solved

Comment: when I surround the statement with using I get this error:
System.IO.FileInfo[]': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: How do you get all images in your project??What mechanism are u using in your project(manually keeping or uploading)??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the IIS express service that is running on my localHost. the process is called iisexpress.exe and it is using the file even after i close the site and try to delete it manually. after I moved back to use the asp.net development sever the issue was gone.
thanks for everyone.